# Calculate average number of attempts in a dice game

Tags: probability, dice

A much more detailed explanation, with changed values, since the other did not match.

So this is for a war game, where I want to calculate the average number of rounds, it takes a unit to kill another, based what statistics that unit has.

Each round consists of the unit makes a number of attacks, where you roll D6.

For an attack you first roll a D6, to see if it hits, and then if it hits, a D6 is rolled to see if it survives. If it survives the hits, it becomes easier to kill it next round.

To hit you have to roll S or less.
If it is more than S, it misses, and that attack is over.
The probability to hit the other unit is then (S/6) and to miss it is 1 - (S/6)

Once it hit the other unit might survive.
Another D6 is rolled and if it is N or less the other unit dies. If it is more than N the other unit survives, but for the next attack N is increased by 1. Next time it is hit, it has to be (N+1) or less to kill it.
So first time it is hit, it is N or less, then (N+1) and then (N+2), until N = 6.

When the unit only has one attack, I can calculate the average number of rounds

First, since the chance to hit is constant, the average number of attempts will be (1/(S/6)).

The second die changes probability, but it can represented as a random variable, that returns the probability of it taking 1, 2, 3 and so on, for the number attacks required to kill it.

If we call this random variable X, and if N starts with N = 4, it will be.

1 = (4/6)
2 = (1-(4/6))*(5/6)
3 = (1-(4/5))*(1-(5/6))*(6/6)

Since there is only one attack pr round, the average number of rounds can be calculated by
(1/(S/6))*E(X)

Where E(X) is the expected number for X

The problem comes, when a unit has more than one attack per round.

Dividing it by 2, for when it has 2 attacks is not correct, and the technique above does not work either. I know it should not work, since the probability for it to hit, is different for when one hit, and two hits.

Comment: A few things are not clear. 1) What happens when first die is S or more? 2) When you say average number of attempts, are you trying to find average value of N when the game ends? 3) when you extend the problem to 4 dice, what are the conditions for each die?

Comment: It will also help if you add your workings of how you are finding the avergae number so one can point out how it can be improved.